# Using Adobe Bridge as a Digital Asset Manager for a team - how to sync keywords?

Tags: asset-management, adobe-bridge

I just joined a new company that only uses File Explorer to organize their source art files, just typing in as many keywords as they can into the filename and searching off that. I'd like to move to using Adobe Bridge for this and utilize Keywords instead, but I'm having trouble with sharing these keywords with the rest of the team (other users can filter on keywords that are already applied, I'm trying to share the list of applicable keywords from the Keywords panel). Details:

1. All the files are on a server location
2. We are using Adobe Bridge CC 2019 on an Adobe Teams CC subscription.

What I've tried:

1. Creating a soft symlink from the AppData folder to a server location - Bridge just removes it and replaces it with a new XML file when it starts.
2. Creating a hard symlink from the AppData folder to a synced OneDrive folder - Bridge also removes this and replaces it with a new XML file either when it starts or when you add a new keyword within Bridge.
3. Creating a shared Bridge cache - keywords do not import on other PCs when browsing the folders I've created a cache for.

Is there any way to sync the keywords file that is in the Bridge local cache between other users on a network?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I have the same need. Thanks

Comment: @Marco I have not - kind of gave up the search after I became the only person on the team, so I could manage it myself. Would love to know if anyone finds something though.

Comment: This is something I would love to know as well. It seems like a huge missed opportunity for Adobe if there is no option.